# Pass python list to C/C++ as 'float*' or 'int*'

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes, pybind11

C/C++

```
void func(float* xyz1, float* xyz2,int n){
     //do something
     for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        printf("%f %f\n",xyz1[i],xyz2[i]);
     }
}
```

Python

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000000
xyz1 = np.random.random((n,)).tolist()
xyz2 = np.random.random((n,)).tolist()

#pass above array to the C/C++ code for further processing.
func(xyz1,xyz2,n) # <-- the call to the c/c++ code
```

I have seen examples that call the C++ code using more high-level data structures like C++'s `array`. However, I simply want to pass it using basic data types like `int` and `float *`

Any simple way of doing this, with say PyBind11 or python's built-in C types?

Comment: To execute C++ code in python, you could use boost python. -> https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `ctypes`. First create a shared object with C Api.`ctypes` does not support C++ but only C. This means that you can use c++ in your source code but you have to provide a C interface without C++ languages features like function overloading or name mangling. Therefor the function definitions are marked with `extern "C"`.

Then load the shared object in python. Set argument types and result types. Finally you can call your function. Here is an example:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

n = 1000000
xyz1 = np.random.random((n,)).tolist()
xyz2 = np.random.random((n,)).tolist()

#pass above array to the C/C++ code for further processing.
Func = ctypes.CDLL("path/to/libFunc.so")
Func.func.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_int]
res = Func.func(xyz1,xyz2,n) # <-- the call to the c/c++ code
```

I didn't test it so possibly there are some errors but I think the idea should be clear. Here is an example I tested:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1) 
project (DotProduct) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) 
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) 

add_library(DotProduct SHARED src/DotProduct.cpp src/DotProduct.h)
```

DotProduct.h:

```
extern "C" double dotProduct(double* l, double* r, unsigned int len);
```

DotProduct.cpp:

```
#include "DotProduct.h" 

double dotProduct(double *l, double *r, unsigned int len) { 
    double sum(0); 

    while (len--) { 
        sum += l[len] * r[len]; 
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```

main.py:

```
import ctypes

def dot_product(v1, v2):    
    l = len(v1)    
    if l != len(v2):        
        return 0    
    vec1 = (ctypes.c_double * l)(*v1)    
    vec2 = (ctypes.c_double * l)(*v2)    
    Dot_Product = ctypes.CDLL("build/lib/libDotProduct.so")      
    Dot_Product.dotProduct.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_uint]    
    Dot_Product.dotProduct.restype = ctypes.c_double
    return Dot_Product.dotProduct(vec1, vec2, l)

vec1 = [2, 2]
vec2 = [2, 3]
print("{} * {} = {}".format(vec1, vec2, dot_product(vec1, vec2)))
```

Comment: Minor point: In your worked example you declared the `dotProduct`  C++ function to take an unsigned int. But in python you state that it takes a `c_int` (a signed int). It should be `c_uint`. It also couldn't hurt to stress the difference between functions with C linkage and C++ linkage a bit more. I don't know how aware OP and future readers will be aware of that difference.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, using your example and combining with the compilation commands and the "extern c" directive I read about here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python, I was able to get this working.